# Is there a linguistic notion of a "static" vs "dynamic" noun?

Tags: semantics, nouns, philosophy-of-language, logic

I would have typed a clearer question in the title, but it would have been way too long.

By "static," I mean a word or phrase that refers to one object, and one object only. ex.

- The Eiffel Tower
- The United States of America
- Bill Gates

By "dynamic," I mean something for which the closest analogy I can think of is a UNIX symlink. 
ex.

- The current president of the US (sort of like a symlink to Donald Trump, where Donald Trump is a "static" noun)
- The pen on the table (again, like a symlink. Unlike the above, there is no canonical name to refer to this object).
- My phone
- Tonight (refers to a period of time, which in this case might be 20180708 190000 - 230000 EST)

Does this difference exist as a linguistic notion? Again, the best analogy I can come up with is comparing a UNIX file (of any type other than symlink) and a UNIX symlink.

Comment: For starters, this kind of thing is covered by semantics. Your distinction is basically the difference between intension and extension.

Comment: @JeremyNeedle Is the material covered by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensional_and_intensional_definitions what you mean? If so, I do not see how intension and extension have to do with my question.

Comment: It's true that they're not precisely congruent, but I think they adequately cover your terms (and a lot more). I'm afraid I'm not a semanticist, so I'm not going to be able to get more elaborate here. I recommend you poke around some more. Look here under Kripke: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_reference_theory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the philosophy of language and modal logic, the conceptions you label "static" and "dynamic" are called [rigid designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_designator) and [flaccid designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-rigid_designator) respecively.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for.